# Is node.js better behind a reverse proxy for sending json?

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

I have to make a web service who can handle many R&W requests (up to 50/seconds) and I think have a static server (Who host Angular.js App, and heavy resources like video and image)

Is it a good idea to have my node.js server behind a reverse proxy like Nginx or Apache? The goal is to reduce the load of the node.js server.

And what communication method must I use between the reverse proxy and node.js? HTTP? CGI? Other?

And what is the best reverse proxy in this case? Nginx? Apache?

Comment: Well, everything is better behind a reverse proxy. So yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't make too much of a difference behind a reverse proxy or not, as for proto, HTTP is fine.